# how to compile extended class in java?

Tags: java, extends

i want to compile `child.java` class an get `child.class`, child class extends parent class.
i want child.class include all necessary code from parent class, in fact i can use it independently.

is it possible?

second Question: suppose we have a .jar library containing a.class , b.class , c.class ... i have make an updated version of a.class, how can i replace the new one with the original a.class in jar?  is it possible ?

sorry for bad English.

Comment: 1) Basically, you can't. Just pack them together or declare the dependency
2) Just re-generate .jar

Comment: my final goal is to update the a.class in jar library, the library is closed source. i first want to extend a.class and generate new a.class and replace with old one, how can i achieve this?

Comment: @arsenal That won't be possible. You could maybe try to rewrite a.class from javadoc contracts and bytecode, but that's just madness.

Answer (score 0):

1) as Dmitry mentioned in the comment is impossible. Even if your parent class did absolutely nothing it's definition will still be checked, and if not found ClassNotFoundException (or similar) will be thrown

2) Is certainly possible and usefull in some situations (patching external library without recompiling everything from sources comes to mind) - see [Is there are way to patch jar files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069539/is-there-are-way-to-patch-jar-files)
Specifically the most usefull (IMO) is CoolBeans's answer:

```
jar uf test.jar com\test\Test.class
```

Note that you have to take care of correct packaging. And it will not work if the jar is signed.