# How to update only modified class file into destination .jar file automatically?

Tags: java

I would like to copy only modified class file into destination .jar automatically?
I have tried jar uf command. but it copies entire class file to jar.

Comment: Why is this necessary? What is the problem with just rebuilding the jar file?

Comment: i have working on many java file outside and would like to update only modified class file into destination jar file automatically.any solution? any option in JAR command only to modified class file.

Comment: `jar uf` should update just the files that you specify. Why doesn't that work, then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069539/is-there-are-way-to-patch-jar-files?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Two options,
1. unzar everything, copy required file build jar again
2. use some tools to do that like winzip, winrar