# Forcing java to recompile bad class

Tags: java, compilation

I have a jar file that i need to make a minor change to. I remove the damaged class files and decompile them with JAD. But after I fix them I need to recompile. When i recompile i obviously get errors, because i am only edditing one files. But i know you can inject modified class files into a jar.
So my question is: Is it possible to force java to compile the files simply so i can reinsert them? The only errors are that the dependancies and packages arent found, but if i put it back in the jar it will find them.

Comment: Not possible. The compiler will always refuse to generate code that it can't assure is typesafe. And for that it MUST have all dependencies available. But assuming you can run your JAR, then you have those dependencies. Why not put them on the classpath for the compiler?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946071/re-compile-a-java-class-from-jar?rq=1

Comment: Welcome Ethan. I'm not sure if fvu just posted a link to an exact duplicate (as for the "force java compiler" part, which is not feasible as Jochen suggested), but I think you should be able to use it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop the same classe as you have with addition changes using implementation of interface and composition of objects. After it develop custom class loader to unload old class and load new. But it is  hard to do.

Comment: That sounds a lot more complicated than extracting the class file from the jar, decompiling it, changing it, compiling it again - with the changed .jar in the classpath) and putting it back in the .jar file.

Comment: have you read question ? quote : When i recompile i obviously get errors, because i am only edditing one files

Comment: yes, I read that, but I don't see any reason why including the .jar file in the classpath would not help against that situation.